# Обновление данных формы через аякс

Tags: php, ajax

В форме через которую добавляются категории через аякс, нужно, чтобы элементы формы select обновлялись после добавления новой категории.

Форма:

```
<form id ="add_category" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Название</label>
    <input type="text" class="uk-input" name="name" id="name" required>

    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Родительская</label>
    <select name="parrent" class="uk-select" id="parrent">
        <option value="" selected>Без родительской</option>
        <div id="addresult_category_list"><?include "updates/category_list.php";?></div>
    </select>

    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Сортировка</label>
    <input type="text" class="uk-input" name="sort" id="sort" required>

    <div class="uk-margin">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Добавить категорию" id="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-default">
    </div>
```

Скрипт добавления в базу:

```
<script>
$("#add_category").submit(function(send){
    send.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updates/add_category.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(html){  
            $("#addresult_category").html(html);
        }  
    });
});
```

Скрипт обновления поля селект:

```
<script>
$("#add_category").submit(function(send2){
    send2.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updates/category_list.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(html){  
            $("#addresult_category_list").html(html);
        }  
    });
});
```

обработчик обновления селекта:

```
<? include "../config.php";// подключение к базе 

            //определение категорий
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
            if($result = $conn->query($sql)){ 
                foreach($result as $row){ 
                $category = $row["name"]; 
                $category_id = $row["id"];
                echo "<option value=\"$category_id\">$category</option>";
            } 
            } else { echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;}

?>
```

После добавления категории, она появляется в списке, но не в поле селект. В чём ошибка?

Comment: " она появляется в списке" --- в каком списке?

Comment: в списке категорий в базе

Answer (score 0):

Видимо надо не

```
$("#addresult_category_list").html(html);
```

а

```
$("#addresult_category_list").append(html);
```

Comment: не работает, увы(